# Error running "firebase deploy --only functions"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, deployment

My code has an error when I'm trying running "firebase deploy --only functions".
Here is my code:

```
app.post('/payments/create', async (request, response) => {
    const total = parseInt(request.query.total);
    console.log('Payment request receive! - ', total);
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: total,
        currency: "usd",
    });
    response.status(201).send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
});
```

Here is my error:
`19:56  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the ecmaVersion in .eslintrc.js

```
parserOptions: {
    // Required for certain syntax usages
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
  },
```